# Translations Slack invitation link is expired

Tags: elementary-website, translation

anyone knows the new invitation like for Translation Slack that would be great, the link in the website is expired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fix has been posted to the website with an updated link. https://github.com/elementary/website/pull/2122